# What can't I parse the API in my Telegram bot code?

Tags: python, api, parsing, bots, telegram

I am trying to create a Telegram bot that allows users to search up recipes that require only ingredients that they have on-hand. It is built with Python and I have a rough code, but before I fine-tune the details, I want to get the basic form of it up and running. Unfortunately, I am facing difficulty in parsing the API for the recipes corresponding to ingredients that the user has listed in his/her message. Specifically, the logged error message is "Error parsing the API". Could someone take a look at my code and help me see what went wrong please?

This is the relevant portion of my code:

```
def handle_messages(messages):
    for message in messages:
        mappedIngreds = []
        for i in range(len(message.text)):
            ingred = message.text[i].lower()
            if i == 0:
                mappedIngreds.append(ingred)
            else:
                mappedIngreds.append(f"+ {ingred}")
 
    # get responses from API
        try:
            response = requests.get(f"{apiURL}{mappedIngreds}{apiId}{apiKey}")
            response.raise_for_status() # for debugging
        except requests.RequestException:
            logging.error("Error connecting to the API")
            return None
 
    # format responses into list of recipes
        try:
            recipes = []
            for i in response.json():
                recipeInfo = {}
                recipeInfo["name"] = i["label"]
                recipeInfo["url"] = i["url"]
 
                recipes.append(recipeInfo)
 
        except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
            logging.error("Error parsing the API")
            return None
 
    # send list of recipes to user
        try:
            bot.reply_to(message.chat.id, "Try these recipes:", *recipeInfo["name"], *recipeInfo["url"], sep="\n")
        except:
            logging.error("Error printing recipes")
```

My full code is here: https://pastebin.com/W0CceAt9

Comment: It is your code that is giving the incomplete error message.  Try just adding `except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError) as e:` and logging the `e`.  Even here there is too much irrelevant code, if you logged `response`, `response.body`, and `response.json()`, you would certainly have your answer.

Comment: @Cireo Okay, thanks for your suggestions! After changing the logging code, how should I fix my code to get the bot to work though? Currently, it does not respond at all to any message sent by the user other than /start and /help (which I used specific command handlers to handle).

Comment: If you were hitting this exception, you almost certainly are either missing `"label" or "info" in the response, or the response wasn't json at all (unlikely, because you did raise_for_status)